# Eclipse error constantly pops up while editing Javascript

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I am working on relatively small (100-300 lines) Javascript files in Eclipse and periodically it gets really upset about some piece of code and pops up this error every time I place the cursor on that line.  The error is:

```
'Requesting JavaScript AST from Selection' has encountered a problem. 
An internal error occured during "Requesting JavaScript AST from selection". 
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

While I am converting this:

```
if(p){
    // enter code here
} else { return false; }
```

into this:

```
if(p){
    // enter code here
} return false;
```

the error pops up several times. Each time it stops my typing and requires me to click the okay button. I then type two more characters and the error appears again.

Any ideas how to either prevent the error or disable whatever Javascript AST is?

This is on Eclipse Java EE, Indigo Service Release 2. It is almost a flat install, only two plugins installed and neither are for SVN and have nothing to do with Javascript.

Comment: You can track the bug [here Bug #342461](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342461)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Eclipse is almost unusable for javascript editing in its current state. I wish there was a way to disable whatever is causing it. I'd rather have a functional notepad than a souped up alert-generator.

Comment: I found a trick! When the error window pops up, don't close it. Just drag it off to the side, focus back on the main window, and new errors won't change the focus.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

At first I thought this was just a trick, but it is working so well, I had to post it as an actual answer.

When the error window pops up, don't close it. Just drag it off to the side, focus back on the main window and keep editing.

When the error happens again Eclipse doesn't change the focus back to the error message. Focus stays in the editing window and you can continue to edit the document.

Comment: This silly answer is actually the better solution. You don't have to disable anything that you would prefer to keep enabled, and you'll be clicking a lot of 'okay' if you have to wait for the bug to be fixed.

Comment: especially because "Mark Occurrences" is valuable functionality and disabling it makes all kinds of other tasks more difficult. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Just incredible, such a complex piece of software and does not have a tick box to disable all warnings :S ... it works, so you get my vote!!!

Comment: In Kepler on Linux, the dialog is modal, so this doesn't work. :(

Comment: Silly as it may sound, but this should be the accepted answer! This works perfectly.

It baffles me why Eclipse insists on endlessly popping up modal alerts for this kind of thing, totally useless. At least this makes it workable.

There are unsolved bugs (and feature requests) in Eclipse that have been there for 5 to 10 years, don't reckon on them ever being solved. It's just software, life goes on.

Answer (score 85):

An even better answer (from the bug report linked by Cliff Ribaudo, comment #10 and others):

Turn off Toggle Mark Occurrences (Alt-Shift-O or the paintbrush icon on the toolbar, which handily, will show you your current state).

Thanks Cliff!

Edited:

[image: Via Preferences]

Comment: I am a bit concerned that turning off "Mark Occurrences" may be diabling some other features that I would like to keep. I can't find any examples of that being true, but I worry still. Any thoughts on that? Do you know what advantages "Mark Occurrences" provides to Javascript developers?

Comment: It's just disabling the feature of highlighting other occurrences of whatever variable, etc you have your cursor on.

So:

    var foo = 17;
    ...
    var bar = findOuterOtter(foo);
    // leave cursor here......^

Would highlight both the declaration and all references to 'foo'.

I never found it worked very well for JavaScript, and I've suspected it of adding to the slowness it would sometimes show (but I'm not convinced either way yet now that I've turned it off).

Comment: // leave cursor here......^

(Sorry, I can't get it to format the code properly in comments, picture the cursor in the last 'foo').

Comment: This solution worked for me too. Though the problem expired when I solved a syntax warning (a missing semicolon).

Answer (score 3):

Likely an eclipse bug. See this thread:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=359005

There is a patch posted there which you  might try.

Answer (score 0):

Ironically, the solution for me was to install another plugin.  After I installed [VJET](http://eclipse.org/vjet/), and set up my JavaScript project to be a VJET-enabled project, the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

just replace the xml in your .project file (which lies in home directory of your eclipse workspace .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>your Project Name</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting this error lately. I am writing Groovy scripts. The fix for me was to update the Groovy plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error with **`gc overhead limit exceeded`** description in details section of error. To take action on it I have added following in configuration and issue resolved.

```
Xms512m
Xmx2048m
```

Ref: [GC overhead limit exceeded problem](https://docs.oseems.com/general/application/eclipse/fix-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

In short, for me it was eclipse memory problem.