# An internal error occurred during: "Requesting JavaScript AST from selection"

Tags: javascript, eclipse, ide

I'm facing unique error/alert-popup while editing JavaScript files in Eclipse and it pops up this error every time I place the cursor on that line.

JS: NullPointerException when cursor is placed at the end of the line containing return statement.

```
foo.bar = function(x) {
    if (xyz) {
      return fn(x);«error»
    }

    return fn(x);«error»

    return (fn(x));«error»

    return new fn(x);«ok»

    return x;«sometimes»

    return "";«error» 

    return x+"x";«error» 

    return this.x;«error»

    return fn(
        x);«error»

    return new fn(
        x);«ok»

    return;«error»  
};
```

- «» — cursor position
- «ok» — no error
- «error» — triggers error
- «sometimes» — I have code that never triggers an exception in that case, but I don’t see a pattern.

If cursor is at the end of the line of a return, this exception happens:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Requesting JavaScript AST from selection".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The Eclipse error is:

```
'Requesting JavaScript AST from Selection' has encountered a problem. 
An internal error occured during "Requesting JavaScript AST from selection". 
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Is there a solution or workaround available to fix the problem?

Comment: Interesting phenomenon, but what's your *question*?

Comment: @Bergi When I'm trying to edit a JS file, my eclipse starts poping up with some error note regularly. I'm unable to write any thing. The moment i place the cursor, at the end of line, it throws the popup.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse error constantly pops up while editing Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334026/eclipse-error-constantly-pops-up-while-editing-javascript)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Simplest solution:**

- Turn off Toggle Mark Occurrences  (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> or the paintbrush icon on the toolbar, which handily, will show you your current state).

  - It's just disabling the feature of highlighting other occurrences of whatever variable, etc you have your cursor on.

**Official solution:**

- You can track the official bug [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342461).
- There is a patch posted [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=359005) which you might try.

Comment: Just for completeness' sake, with the Mac version (I'm on Eclipse Helios) the shortcut to Toggle Mark Occurrences is <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (the letter O, not the number zero).

Comment: Altough this is the correct answer to eliminate the bug, there is a topic [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334026/eclipse-error-constantly-pops-up-while-editing-javascript)
And the **accepted answer** worth reading

Answer (score 2):

Opening JavaScript files in text editor helps. You may like to change the default default file association for js files to Text Editor.